# How to set secure cookie using heroku + node.js + express?

Tags: node.js, cookies, heroku, express

I have a node.js app running on the Cedar stack and I'm puzzled why secure cookies don't work.

```
"express": "3.0.3",
"node": ">=0.8.14",

...
app.use(express.session({
        secret : 'somesecret',
        store : // store works fine, sessions are stored
        key : 'sid',
        cookie : {
            secure : true, // it works without the secure flag (cookie is set)
            proxy : true,  // tried using this as well, no difference
            maxAge: 5184000000 // 2 months
        }
}));
...
```

On localhost everything works fine, but on heroku I don't seem to be able to set a secure cookie. What am I doing wrong? The [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing) say the load balancer terminates SSL, is it something to configure over there?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are correct that Heroku terminates SSL before it reaches your app. That causes express to see non-ssl traffic, and that's likely why it's refusing to set the cookie when running on Heroku.

Heroku sets a `X-Forwarded-Proto` header with the original protocol. I haven't tested this, but according to the documentation, you have to tell express to respect the information in that header by setting `trust proxy` as documented [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/New-features-in-3.x). Additional details found under `req.protocol` [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html).

Comment: Thanks, you're right about having to be explicit. I figured I misplaced the 'proxy' property, it is for the session options, but I put it inside the cookie => wrong.

Comment: I'll accept this answer for pointing out the effect of Heroku terminating SSL connections even though the `trust proxy` setting is _not_ related to cookie handling. Once SO allows, I'll also post my fixed code.

Answer (score 17):

### Solution

The problem was that I set `proxy: true` in the wrong place, it should look like as follows:

```
...
app.enable('trust proxy'); // optional, not needed for secure cookies
app.use(express.session({
    secret : 'somesecret',
    store : ..., // store works fine, sessions are stored
    key : 'sid',
    proxy : true, // add this when behind a reverse proxy, if you need secure cookies
    cookie : {
        secure : true,
        maxAge: 5184000000 // 2 months
    }
}));
...
```

Add as well `app.enable('trust proxy');` suggested by @friism in case you want to use `req.protocol` somewhere in the Heroku hosted app.

Comment: Shouldn't you use an extra option with trust proxy to limit it to only trust the 1st/1st few proxy/proxies or something?

Comment: If you have to, you can more granularly control trust. Back then, I think express 3.0.3 did not document that, nor I was concerned about that security aspect, but sure, the proxy-addr package gives you that level of control.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [cookie-session](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session) it should look like this:

```js
app.use require('cookie-session') 
   secret: '<secret>'
   secureProxy: true
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me getting `secure: true` to work on Heroku:

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
```

Straight from the current `expression-session` docs, under "cookie.secure".