# Anyway to set proxy setting in passportjs?

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, sails.js, passport.js

Currently, I am using sails framework which is based on expressjs and using passportjs(http://passportjs.org/) to do yammer authentication.

I have problem when deploying my node app on server which is behind the company proxy. It cannot connect to yammer for OAuth2 authentication.

The error is as follow:

```
error: failed to obtain access token (Error: connect ETIMEDOUT)
    at /root/rlps/node_modules/passport-yammer/node_modules/passport-oauth/lib/passport-oauth/strategies/oauth2.js:125:38
    at /root/rlps/node_modules/passport-yammer/lib/passport-yammer/strategy.js:72:20
    at ClientRequest. (/root/rlps/node_modules/passport-yammer/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:129:5)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at CleartextStream.socketErrorListener (http.js:1547:9)
    at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.onerror (tls.js:1437:17)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:459:13)
```

I believe it is because the proxy is blocking the way. I tried to set everything in environment value (like http_proxy and https_proxy) but seems the code does not acknowledge them and need to config it in somewhere in passportjs instead.

So, any good way to set proxy setting in passportjs or solve this proxy issue in nodejs?

Comment: We need more details. What error are you getting and where does it originate? Can you isolate the relevant code and post it? Is this a problem with a secure cookie, and does the problem only show when the server is behind a proxy? If so, and if you are using Express, check out the `trust proxy` setting in the Express [docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app-settings).

Comment: If I may continue under the assumption that you are using Express, check out [How to set secure cookie using heroku + node.js + express?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463972/how-to-set-secure-cookie-using-heroku-node-js-express)

Comment: sorry for unclear question. I will add more details.

Comment: added! if anything is still not clear, please point it out.

Comment: Well, it's not a cookie problem. Does the `callbackURL` you set for the `new YammerStrategy` have a hardcoded port number? Does the proxy reroute traffic to a different port?

Comment: You might be able to narrow down the problem by making the requests manually using the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module, based on the Yammer [Server Side Flow](https://developer.yammer.com/authentication/#a-oauth2) docs.

Comment: I understand now by looking into the passport-yammer library code. It does not provide anyway to send request via proxy. Hope there is a easy way to set global-wide proxy for node app without fixing inside the passport-yammer library.

Comment: You can try set http proxy via npm config.

`
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
`

http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/

Answer (score 7):

Node.js doesn't use the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` variables by default.

You have to tweak the `agent` parameter for the request but since you don't have control on that library you can change globally like this:

```
npm i tunnel --save
```

create a setup_proxy.js:

```
var env = process.env;

if (!env['http_proxy']) return;

var localUrls = [
  'http://some-internal-url.mycompany.local',
];

var url    = require('url');
var tunnel = require('tunnel');
var proxy = url.parse(env['http_proxy']);

var tunnelingAgent = tunnel.httpsOverHttp({
  proxy: {
    host: proxy.hostname,
    port: proxy.port
  }
});

var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');

var oldhttpsreq = https.request;
https.request = function (options, callback) {

  if (localUrls.some(function (u) {
    return ~u.indexOf(options.host);
  })){
    return oldhttpsreq.apply(https, arguments);
  }

  options.agent = tunnelingAgent;
  return oldhttpsreq.call(null, options, callback);
};

var oldhttpreq = http.request;
http.request = function (options, callback) {

  if (localUrls.some(function (u) {
    return ~u.indexOf(options.host);
  })){
    return oldhttpreq.apply(http, arguments);
  }

  options.agent = tunnelingAgent;
  return oldhttpreq.call(null, options, callback);
};
```

require this at the very beginning `require('./setup_proxy')`.

Notice that this use the same `http_proxy` env variable for http and https traffic, but the code is easy to follow if you need to change.

Comment: Why do you use `var oldhttpreq = https.request;` before the `http.request`? I also get an infinite loop + `Maximium Stack Size Exceeded`

Comment: @AndiGiga we are monkeypatching the function and we need to keep a reference to the original function.

Comment: But why `var oldhttpreq = https.request;` not `var oldhttpreq = http.request;` `http` vs `https`

Comment: Also aren't `requires` singeltons as long as they are not required in a submodule with `index.js`? So it is anyways not the original function?

Comment: GOT IT! thanks for pointing that out. "Aren't requires singletons?", these are just objects and are cached.

Comment: Meanwhile I found a different solution for proxying my outgoing connections: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127408/nodejs-passport-oauth2-proxy Maybe this is of interest for you as well?