# How to use proxy agent in nodejs with express

Tags: node.js, express, proxy

I'm trying to access the google authentication from my node application using passportJS. Unfortunately, I have to access the google info using the company proxy. My app is using express.

So, I'd like to know how can I include a proxy agent in my node application. I was looking for some solutions and I just found these solutions:

- [node-http-proxy-agent](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-http-proxy-agent)
- [node-proxy-agent](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-proxy-agent)

Unfortunately, I'm new node developer, and I really don't know how to use these solutions with express. So, I'd like to know if someone had the same issue and how did you solve that kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `proxy-agent` modules are meant for use with *outgoing* HTTP client requests. That is, when calling [`http.get()` and friends](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback).

There is no [`http.Agent`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) for HTTP Server instances, which is what express exposes.

Instead, I think you'll have to ask the PassportJS team how to pass an `http.Agent` instance in to PassportJS. There is [this relevant SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533735/anyway-to-set-proxy-setting-in-passportjs), but the accepted answer is really a hack, and not something that I would recommend. The more proper way would be for PassportJS to accept an `agent` option, but I can't find any mention of that in its documentation.