# Cannot configure Hyperledger Composer with multiuser authetication

Tags: node.js, authentication, proxy, hyperledger-composer, multi-user

I am following the tutorial Using Google OAUTH2.0 with a REST server (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest). After login with success into my Google account, I get this error on the browser:

```js
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "InternalOAuthError",
    "message": "Failed to obtain access token",
    "oauthError": {
      "errno": "ENOTFOUND",
      "code": "ENOTFOUND",
      "syscall": "getaddrinfo",
      "hostname": "accounts.google.com",
      "host": "accounts.google.com",
      "port": 443
    },
    "stack": "InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain access token\n    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/home/composer/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:379:17)\n    at /home/composer/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:166:45\n    at /home/composer/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:191:18\n    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/composer/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:162:5)\n    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)\n    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)\n    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)\n    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)\n    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:66:8)\n    at args.(anonymous function) (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/event-loop-inspector/index.js:138:29)\n    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)\n    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)"
  }
}
```

I am behind a corporate proxy. So, I suspect there it is the problem but I am not sure.

Following the tutorial instructions, I edited the file Dockerfile for adding npm configuration of the proxy (ip and port with the right data):

> FROM hyperledger/composer-rest-server
>   RUN npm config set proxy http://ip:port && npm config set https-proxy http://ip:port && \
>   npm install --production loopback-connector-mongodb passport-google-oauth2 request https-proxy-agent && \
>   npm cache clean --force && \
>   ln -s node_modules .node_modules

Also, and I added request and https-proxy-agent modules for implementing the workaround explaining here: [Use Passport.js Behind Corporate Firewall for Facebook Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639337/use-passport-js-behind-corporate-firewall-for-facebook-strategy), but with no success.

I built the Docker image composer-rest-server like this:

```
docker build -t myorg/composer-rest-server --build-arg http_proxy=http://ip:port --build-arg https_proxy=http://ip:port .
```

When I ran the Docker container, this was the log:

> [2018-09-28T10:48:18.240Z] PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
>   [2018-09-28T10:48:18.318Z] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:composer-rest-server id:0
>   [2018-09-28T10:48:18.325Z] PM2 log: App name:composer-rest-server id:0 online
>   WARNING: NODE_APP_INSTANCE value of '0' did not match any instance config file names.
>   WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
>   Discovering types from business network definition ...
>   (node:15) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
>   Discovering the Returning Transactions..
>   Discovered types from business network definition
>   Generating schemas for all types in business network definition ...
>   Generated schemas for all types in business network definition
>   Adding schemas for all types to Loopback ...
>   Added schemas for all types to Loopback
>   Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000
>   Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer

And, after login to my Google account, this was the log:

> Unhandled error for request GET /auth/google/callback?code=4%2FbAC3w3UnnALN4kKQD8RdjfC_wrXJeFAojIHKOANISGWYn-zvIzTeO24P96T_SaJDhVBPcbdqrmLxUyv9IajeYrg&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.me+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.profile.agerange.read+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.profile.language.read+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile: InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain access token
>       at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/home/composer/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:379:17)
>       at /home/composer/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:166:45
>       at /home/composer/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:191:18
>       at ClientRequest. (/home/composer/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:162:5)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:66:8)
>       at args.(anonymous function) (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/event-loop-inspector/index.js:138:29)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)

And this is COMPOSER_PROVIDERS variable, with the right clientID and clientSecret values:

```
COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
"google": {
    "provider": "google",
    "module": "passport-google-oauth2",
    "clientID": "REPLACE_WITH_CLIENT_ID",
    "clientSecret": "REPLACE_WITH_CLIENT_SECRET",
    "authPath": "/auth/google",
    "callbackURL": "/auth/google/callback",
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
    "successRedirect": "/",
    "failureRedirect": "/"
}
```

Anyone could tell me where is the problem?

Thanks.

PD: Sorry for this brick!

Comment: Are you trying to use google or github? At your log error, you have: Unhandled error for request GET /auth/github: Error: Cannot GET /auth/github

check your COMPOSER_PROVIDERS variable, could be still using the passport-github

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the mistake. I copied other output for the log when I login to my Google account. I have already edited I copied the right log. Could you, please, check it again?

Comment: Can you paste your COMPOSER_PROVIDERS variable?

Comment: I have just added it at the end of the question. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Can you try to use github oauth2 example? For me worked smooth. I didn't try with google yet.

Comment: Yes, I did it before the google one. And it was OK, after implementing the following workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639337/use-passport-js-behind-corporate-firewall-for-facebook-strategy. Are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: No I'm not... maybe this is your issue, not sure if I can help now. I will try to use google but not sure when.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the intent.