# HTTPS on Heroku - Automatic but Not Functional?

Tags: python, heroku, cookies, https

I recently deployed a Flask application on Heroku just for testing purposes. However, I noticed that the URL was in HTTPS even though I didn't have any SSL Certificates or enabled Automatic Certificate Management. Can someone please explain why this is the case?

[image: deployment]

Regardless, I still noticed that my cookies were not being saved even though I had `SameSite=None` enabled - which means it's showing an HTTPS URL but the connection is not in HTTPS..?

I appreciate any support this community provides :)

Comment: It looks like you are not using a custom domain.. which means be default heroku is going to use ssl, whether you've enabled that option or not.

Comment: @sur.la.route Thanks for your comment! Does that also explain why the cookies were not saved (is it a default setting?)

Comment: For the cookie problem... [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463972/how-to-set-secure-cookie-using-heroku-node-js-express) seems to explain it pretty well. not sure what language you are programming in, but it can probably be translated :)